# Angular load additional data in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have an ng-repeat that has a bunch of ids and loops over them. I then want to load the data from an external source. So let's say I have an array

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

And I have an ng-repeat that loops over then shows

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
...
```

I want to load additional details from an external source (firebase) to get the details of the users profile so I can show first name and last name which is part of another section and then load them by calling

```
http://firebase/users/user_1
http://firebase/users/user_2
...
```

And then somehow map it to the dom or scope so I can then print it using normal angular stuff.

Any idea on how to do this best?

Comment: See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/extending-services.html#section-firebasearray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I'd do is make that array usable both before and after the extra data is loaded. I'll assume your full user object has field `id`

```
$scope.users = [1,2,3,4].map(function(id) {
    return {id: id};
});
```

This should let you use `ng-repeat` like this

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
    {{user.id}}
</div>
```

Now, in your controller, load up the user details. I'll assume you have a `User` `$resource` or similar service

```
var userPromises = $scope.users.map(function(user) {
    return User.get({id: 'user_' + user.id}).$promise;
});
$q.all(userPromises).then(function(users) {
    $scope.users = users;
});
```

Then just change your template to use the extra details

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
    {{user.id}}
    <dl ng-if="user.$resolved">
        <dt>First name</dt>
        <dd>{{ user.firstName }}</dd>

        <dt>Last name</dt>
        <dd>{{ user.lastName }}</dt>
    </dl>
</div>
```